# why is it wrong with the declaration of an array type with at least 2 elements?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

codes:

```
type StringArray = readonly string[];
type stringArrayWith2Elements = [string, string];
type stringArrayWith2PlusElements = StringArray & {
  1: string;
}
const myArr: stringArrayWith2PlusElements = ['a', 'b'];
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwIL3gQxFAvFPBNgCYD2yANngM4IqoDaAugNwBQHokU9SaTDhAB1RMAAWAJgCiVCAFsIyYLQJQm-RgBo+DNOy49oWwVlxjJUgApUArrTmLlq9XAEZzeAGRQA3hxQQVAAjABceh6cAL5cAMaU9FAKIEIRpp7CltK2Dk5KKmqETADk2CW6JQBGJYZAA) returns the following error:

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'stringArrayWith2PlusElements'.
> Property '1' is missing in type 'string[]' but required in type '{ 1: string; }'.

if I change `stringArrayWith2PlusElements` to the following, it works:

```
type stringArrayWith2PlusElements = StringArray & {
    0: string;
    1: string;
}
```

see the updated [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwIL3gQxFAvFPBNgCYD2yANngM4IqoDaAugNwBQHokU9SaTDhAB1RMAAWAJgCiVCAFsIyYLQJQm-RgBo+DNOy49oWwVlxjJUgApUArrTmLlq9XAEZzeAGRQA3hxQQVAADABceh6cwVAAjBGmqJwAvlwAxpT0UAogQgn6nsKW0rYOTkoqaoRMAOTYNbo1AEY1hkA).

Comment: It turns out that the type checker tries to detect a "tuple-like" array by checking specifically if it has a known `0` key (see definition of `isTupleLikeType()` in [checker.ts](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/main/src/compiler/checker.ts)). A `0` key gives context to interpret an array as a tuple; otherwise it doesn't trigger and infers as a `string[]` only (and fails to type check). I'm not saying this behavior is good, that's just what the answer is.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer post explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz Please write up an answer post explaining.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript has not anticipated your use case.  When inferring the type of an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) like `['a', 'b']`, the compiler decides from [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) whether to treat it as a plain [array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) (an unordered array of dynamic length) as a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) (an ordered array usually of known length).  With an assignment like `const myArr: MyType = ['a', 'b']`, the type `MyType` provides the context.

I don't see this documented anywhere, but if you look at the type checker code at [`checker.ts`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/v5.2.2/src/compiler/checker.ts), there's a function named `isTupleLikeType()` impemented as

```
function isTupleLikeType(type: Type): boolean {
    let lengthType;
    return isTupleType(type) ||
        !!getPropertyOfType(type, "0" as __String) || // <-- HERE
        isArrayLikeType(type) && !!(
          lengthType = getTypeOfPropertyOfType(type, "length" as __String)
        ) && everyType(lengthType, t => !!(t.flags & TypeFlags.NumberLiteral));
}
```

The important bit here is that if a type has `0` as a known key, then it is considered "tuple-like" and will provide context for inferring a tuple type.  If `MyType` is an intersection of a plain array type and an object with a key of `0`, then the array literal will be given a tuple type, and the assignment will succeed if that tuple type is assignable to `MyType`.  So given `type MyType = readonly string[] & {0: string, 1: string}`, the value `["a", "b"]` will be inferred as something like `[string, string]`, which is assignable to `MyType`.

But if `MyType` is an intersection of a plain array type and an object without a key of `0`, then the array literal will only be given a plain array type, and the assignment will only succeed if that plain array type is assignable to `MyType`.  So given `type MyType = readonly string[] & {1: string}`, the value `["a", "b"]` will be inferred as something like `string[]`, which is *not* assignable to `MyType`.

So there you go.  This answers why one succeeds and one fails.  TypeScript doesn't support this use case.  That's not intended to be a value judgment; i's possible you could file a feature request asking for support for your use case, and maybe it would be well received (although generally they'd want to see a lot of community feedback before considering it).  But that's the current status of TypeScript 5.2.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. I haven't seen documentation for TupleLikeType anywhere either. But when I raised issues in the github repository, I was assumed to know about it.

Comment: A new observasion: If I declare and initilize myArr as `const myArr: stringArrayWith2PlusElements = ['a', 'b'] as const;` typescript won't raise any error. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwIL3gQxFAvFPBNgCYD2yANngM4IqoDaAugNwBQokU9SamHCADqiYAAsATAFEqEALYRkwWgShM+jADS8Gadl3DRNArLlETJABSoBXWrIVKVauPwxm8AMigBvDlBQAIwAXLrunAC+HADGlPRQ8iCCYSYeQhZSNvaOisqqhEwA5NhFOkUARkUsUNiqccj0nEA)